# Calling sequential on parallel stream makes all previous operations sequential

Tags: java, multithreading, java-stream, forkjoinpool

I've got a significant set of data, and want to call slow, but clean method and than call fast method with side effects on result of the first one. I'm not interested in intermediate results, so i would like not to collect them.

Obvious solution is to create parallel stream, make slow call , make stream sequential again, and make fast call. The problem is, ALL code executing in single thread, there is no actual parallelism.

Example code:

```
@Test
public void testParallelStream() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException
{
    ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2);
    Set<String> threads = forkJoinPool.submit(()-> new Random().ints(100).boxed()
            .parallel()
            .map(this::slowOperation)
            .sequential()
            .map(Function.identity())//some fast operation, but must be in single thread
            .collect(Collectors.toSet())
    ).get();
    System.out.println(threads);
    Assert.assertEquals(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2, threads.size());
}

private String slowOperation(int value)
{
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Thread.currentThread().getName();
}
```

If I remove `sequential`, code executing as expected, but, obviously, non-parallel operation would be call in multiple threads.

Could you recommend some references about such behavior, or maybe some way to avoid temporary collections?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Switching the stream from `parallel()` to `sequential()` worked in the initial Stream API design, but caused many problems and finally the implementation was [changed](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/lambda/lambda/jdk/file/29664d18c7d1/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/AbstractPipeline.java), so it just turns the parallel flag on and off for the whole pipeline. The current documentation is indeed vague, but it was improved in [Java-9](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Parallelism):

> The stream pipeline is executed sequentially or in parallel depending on the mode of the stream on which the terminal operation is invoked. The sequential or parallel mode of a stream can be determined with the `BaseStream.isParallel()` method, and the stream's mode can be modified with the `BaseStream.sequential()` and `BaseStream.parallel()` operations. The most recent sequential or parallel mode setting applies to the execution of the entire stream pipeline.

As for your problem, you can collect everything into intermediate `List` and start new sequential pipeline:

```
new Random().ints(100).boxed()
        .parallel()
        .map(this::slowOperation)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        // Start new stream here
        .stream()
        .map(Function.identity())//some fast operation, but must be in single thread
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: The sentence you have cited is exactly the same in the Java 8 version, to be found at the same place, the last paragraph of the class documentation. Generally, you find more information at the [package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps)(see “Parallelism”) than at the [particular method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#parallel--), not only with parallel/sequential mode (compare with Reduction, for example).

Comment: Well spotted! I knew that it was [updated](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/jdk/rev/d52b2d49bf04) (I even participated in discussion and [convinced](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2015-August/034773.html) Stuart to add a special note for `concat`), but for some reason found the wrong place. Post edited.

Answer (score 2):

In the current implementation a Stream is either all parallel or all sequential.  While the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#parallel--) isn't explicit about this and it could change in the future it does say this is possible.

> S parallel()
>
> Returns an equivalent stream that is parallel. May return itself, either because the stream was already parallel, or because the underlying stream state was modified to be parallel.

If you need the function to be single threaded, I suggest you use a Lock or synchronized block/method.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but sync method becomes bottleneck and intermediate collection works faster(confirmed by jmh). In this particular case I'm more interested in performance, then memory.